# 'Could not find installable ISAM'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using Windows 7 64 Bit OS. When trying to read an excel file, It gives an error - 'Could not find installable ISAM'.
I tried to install AccessDatabaseEngineX64 but it said, the Office 2007 has 32 bit components, so went ahead & installed AccessDatabaseEngineX86. I also changed the Platform to 'X86' from 'Any CPU'. The issue persits. How can I fix it.

```
string fileName = fileUploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;

string fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

string filePath = "~/Temp/"+fileName;

FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

string connString ="";

if(fileType==".xls")

  connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource={0};
                Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\";",filePath); 
else if(fileType==".xlsx")    
  connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource={0};
               Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\";",filePath);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

conn.Open;   //Error Here
```

Comment: Do you have setup the IIS to run 32bit ASP.NET apps?

Comment: Its still under development. So IIS not set up yet

Comment: try this: ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                            "Data Source=c:\Book1.xls;" +
                            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""" source:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55d9545e-073e-4a24-bf04-f1ce16429ad4/could-not-find-installable-isam-with-excel-file

Comment: Thank you . That link helped me out. The error was DataSource. It should be Data Source instead